# Odd-one-out of RACECAR, MURDRUM, SAGAS, ATTACK, and REPAPER

Tags: word-property, odd-one-out

The secret agency Tycoon emailed a code to its agent 006. They are "**RACECAR**, **MURDRUM**, **SAGAS**, **ATTACK**, and **REPAPER**". Leaving one which is fake, all other words have something in common. Can you help in finding the fake word?

(Source: https://www.hitbullseye.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my answer:

> ATTACK isn't a palindrome, so that's the fake word.

Comment: Oh didn't see you answered. Hope you get the check!

Comment: Ah it's alright :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the one that doesn't begin and end with the same letters (not a palindrome)? Attack...
>  Credit: not me, I initially stopped reading too soon.

Comment: Oh yeah say that

Comment: Yes, you are very close to the real answer. (Your answer is also correct.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> ATTACK
>  The other words have the following in common which ATTACK does not:
>  - Palindromic
>  - Prime length
>  - Begin with a consonant